# how to get image size from a jquery json parse?

Tags: jquery, json, image-size

how to get image size from a jquery json parse? I put a `each function`, first download all the images to the html part then try to use `width()` & `height()` to the the image size, but I met some trouble in getting `width()` & `height()` are ahead of the image loading.

example code in http://jsfiddle.net/7eLj4/

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = '[{"image":"http:\/\/pcdn.500px.net\/6269271\/a85b2995b4d80748831492be5e8a3689895a2b0e\/4.jpg"},{"image":"http:\/\/pcdn.500px.net\/5953805\/d0dd841969187f47e8ad9157713949b4b95b3bda\/4.jpg"},{"image":"http:\/\/pcdn.500px.net\/5735750\/0dd26cb9f53b7bbbedf1b65c0d0aac013f77466c\/4.jpg"}]';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
    $.each(obj, function(index,item) {
       $('#imagewrap').append('<img class="images" src="'+item.image+'" />');         
    });
    $('.images').each(function(){
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        alert(width+''+height+''+imgsrc);           
    });   
});​
```

Html code:

```
<div id="imagewrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to the image load event:

```
$('.images').bind('load', function () {
  // do something here
});
```

Here's your fiddle updated to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/7eLj4/5/

Answer (score 0):

Call the function that accesses the `.width()` and `.height()` of an image from an `onload` function for each image. `onload` will get called after the image has completed downloading.

```
myImage.onload = function() {
    var accurateWidth = myImage.width();
}
```